# Converting JSON data into a nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file that is a single line with about 80 "sets" of data like this:

```
{"Chris": "(597)966-9123", "Bailey": "(311)790-3765"
```

I have a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
data = {'Name': {},
    'Contact': {}
    }
```

It might seem clear that what I'm trying to do is take the names and phone numbers from the JSON and sort them into the nested dictionary under the correct keys. However, I am running into a lot of errors. The main block I'm struggling with is here:

```
try:
  with open('contacts.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    data['Name'] =
    data['Contact'] =
```

In the 2 equal signs I have tried splitting (dict errors), a for loop to sort, casting data to a list, initializing data to other data types. I'm just getting frustrated with this and cant figure it out.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Please provide more code with the mentioned logic.

Comment: Shouldn't your final `data` output be a list, not a dict. I mean a list of dicts, where each item has `Name` and `Contact` keys. If so, you can easily do this with a list comprehension.

Comment: `json.loads()` will help you to convert JSON into dictionary, but first, you have to import JSON module by `import json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the following might work

```
data = json.loads(file)
all_data = {
    'Name': [],
    'Contact': []
}
for name, contact in data.items():
    all_data['Name'].append(name)
    all_data['Contact'].append(contact)
print(all_data)
```

The output will be:

```
{'Name': ['Chris', 'Bailey'], 'Contact': ['(597)966-9123', '(311)790-3765']}
```

Comment: Thats the exact output i'm looking for, however I'm getting the AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

EDIT: I missed changing the curly brackets to square in all_data. I'm confused if this would still be considered a dictionary object, but the output is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Dicts aren't supposed to keep order :). Well, maybe in 3.7 it really keep it. But are you really using the correct datastructure ?.
Perhaps you want a nested lists instead of nested dicts.

Try this:

```
>>> with open('Contacts.json', 'r') as file_:
...   x = json.load(file_)

>>> x = {"Chris": "(597)966-9123", "Bailey": "(311)790-3765"}
>>> d = {'Name': [], 'Contact': []}
>>> for key, val in x.items():
...   d['Name'].append(key)
...   d['Contact'].append(val)
... 
>>> d
{'Name': ['Chris', 'Bailey'], 'Contact': ['(597)966-9123', '(311)790-3765']}
```

You could certainly have a `OrderedDict` for the `Name` and `Contact`, but do you ?

Or maybe you just want,

```
>>> sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
[('Bailey', '(311)790-3765'), ('Chris', '(597)966-9123')]
>>> sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]), reverse=True)
[('Chris', '(597)966-9123'), ('Bailey', '(311)790-3765')]
```

Comment: I don't care about the dictionary keeping order, I just want the names to go in the name key and phones in the contact key in my nested dictionary. Is that possible with a JSON?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a reply yet to the question in my comment, I'll post this as a way to get a list of dicts:

```
with open('contacts.json') as file:
  data = json.load(file)
  new_data = [{"Name": name, "Contact": contact} for (name, contact) in data.items()]
```